# function with non declared variables / variables as functions

Tags: javascript

I have two questions regarding the following code sample:

```js
function greaterThan(n) {
  return m => m > n;
}
let greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
console.log(greaterThan10(11));
//returns true
```

From what I understand the function `greaterThan(n)` returns a function which takes the parameter `m` but here it starts to get tricky for me:

1. Why is this `m` not declared and still properly working within this code sample?
2. `greaterThan10` is declared as a variable in line 4 and it is inheriting the value of `greaterThan(10)`. How can it behave like a function in line 5, where this "variable" takes another integer?

Comment: "*returns a function itself which is called m*" no, the parameter it takes is called `m`

Comment: "*How can it behave like a function in line 5*" you already said it: "*the function greaterThan(n) returns a function*"

Comment: `m` is declared on the left hand side of the `=>` (i.e. as the name of the only parameter the function takes).

Comment: Are you familiar with _arrow function_ syntax? `m => m > n` is a valid function in its own right.

Comment: That arrow function is equivalent to `function(m) { return m > n; }`. Does that help?

Comment: `the function greaterThan(n) returns a function which take the parameter m`... no, the greaterThan function accepts m as an _input_ value, and then it then returns a function, which itself (when called) returns a boolean (true/false) which is the result of calculating whether m is greater than n or not

Answer (score 0):

`greaterThan` is a higher order function; it returns another function that it creates based on the inputs.

`m => m > n` is an arrow function.

It's equivalent to this:

```js
function greaterThan(n) {
  return function (m) {
    return m > n;
  }
}
let greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
console.log(greaterThan10(11));
//returns true
```